# language not supported while consuming API

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

I am using Spring boot and gson  to consume API.

[image]

but unfortunately nepali words in the response of API is not supported. and so when i save response in my database it adds some weird characters instead of actual value.

I have added these configurations on `application.properties`

```
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=utf-8

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8

server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
```

but it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your request and response Content-Type Header to accept UTF-8, Something like:

```
Content-Type application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Also, You can add mandatory file encoding for spring (Which will disable the server from starting if the encoding is not correct):

```
spring.mandatory_file_encoding=UTF-8
```